# React native expo error, npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

[image: I deleted the node modules and tried to install it again, while doing npmm install, I'm getting this error.]

How to resolve this error... I tried to create a new project and there also i got same npm error while installin dependencies.